# How can I ask if an English phrase is based on some Japanese phrase?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

Sometimes I come across an English phrase that looks a bit odd, and I wonder if it's based on some Japanese phrase unbeknownst to me. Assuming that such a question would make sense, how can I ask an average Japanese-speaker, as opposed to a linguist, about this?

For example, if I came across "a carp laid on a chopping block", or "steel and rice coalition", and there was some reason I suspected it was based on Japanese, how would I ask them about it in Japanese?

Comment: I think it's better to write the question itself in English, if possible, some context where you encountered those phrases.

Comment: ことわざ的な？感じですかとか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 日本語由来の言葉ですか？ ("Is the phrase Japanese-origin?")
- 元は日本語ですか？ ("Is the origin Japanese?")
- 日本語のことわざですか？ ("Is that a Japanese proverb?")
- どこの国の言い方ですか？ ("A way of saying of what country is it?")

You can also use 慣用句 (="idiomatic phrase"), but this may sound a bit too stiff in casual conversations.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative: "その表現、もともと日本語でした？”

Comment: What does this phrase literally mean?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm 「その表現(は)」→ "That expression is", 「もともと」→ "originally", 「日本語でした(か)?」→ "Was it Japanese language?" ---> So it literally means: "Was that expression originally Japanese?"